# How do I get the control points of a bezier line?

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

I do have a set of `N` points. How can I fit a Bezier curve of order three through these points? I know the formula to get a Bezier line from three control points, but is there also a way to get the control points?

Edit: the `N` points are randomly placed.

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to fit the Bezier curve through all $N$ points? If $N > 4$, there will not necessarily be a curve that goes through all the points.

Comment: That's the question. The line should only approximate the $N$ points

Comment: In that case, what is your approximation "metric"? Normally, when trying to fit a best fit curve $(y = f(x))$ to points $\{(x_1, y_1), ..., (x_, y_n)\}$, the objection is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (f(x_i)-y_i)^2$. However, that doesn't work in this case because Bezier curves may not be a function in $x$.

Comment: Yes I get that, thanks for your help. I think that problem is not yet solved, because I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Are you looking for references to existing research (curve fitting is a complex topic), or would you rather get some examples how to begin on your own?  If you are trying to solve a problem, the first makes more sense; if you are looking to learn and explore first (before delving to the rather heavy reading papers on the subject), the latter makes more sense.

Comment: There is in general a unique cubic Bezier curve through 4 points (with $x=at^3+bt^2+ct+d,y=a't^3+b't^2+c't+d'$, you have to know 8 coefficients. If you constraint it to pass through 4 points, you get 8 equations in 8 unknowns that, in general have a solution). Adding another constraint (passing through a fifth point, and even N points will be impossible in general). What you need is a **spline curve**.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will have a look at that.